# I 'can only post once every 40 minutes' but I haven't posted at all today

Tags: support, bug

I was trying to ask a question and being told that I cannot submit it, because "You can only post once every 40 minutes", but I had not posted recently in SharePoint, and my profile only showed a comment in the unrelated RPG site. I was allowed to post finally, but according to my history that was 33 minutes after the comment.

I haven't had this issue on other parts of the Stack Exchange network, so I came to Meta for assistance, but couldn't even post here for the same reason!

I can potentially understand why people are prevented from repeat posts on the main site, but why am I also prevented from asking about it on Meta? And why 40 minutes? That seems arbitrarily long.